# How to mark an Airflow DAG run as failed if any task fails?

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to make an Airflow DAG fail if any task fails?

I usually have some cleaning up tasks at the end of a DAG and as it is now, whenever the last task succeeds the whole DAG is marked as a success.

Comment: Might be connected to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1515?attachmentSortBy=dateTime

Comment: This might be related but it is not the same, in my case the task is executed but the whole dag is marked as success instead of failed

Comment: I have the same problem. I would argue this to be a bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another solution can be to add a final PythonOperator that checks the status of all tasks in this run:

```
final_status = PythonOperator(
    task_id='final_status',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=final_status,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE, # Ensures this task runs even if upstream fails
    dag=dag,
)

def final_status(**kwargs):
    for task_instance in kwargs['dag_run'].get_task_instances():
        if task_instance.current_state() != State.SUCCESS and \
                task_instance.task_id != kwargs['task_instance'].task_id:
            raise Exception("Task {} failed. Failing this DAG run".format(task_instance.task_id))
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as I can simply write this operator once and simply put is at the end of any DAG without changing any operator before.

Comment: Is it possible to get and print log and trace of the failed task ?

Answer (score 4):

Facing a similar problem. It is not a bug but it could be a nice feature to add this property to Dag.

As a workaround, I you can push a XCOM variable during the task that is allowed to fail and in the downstream tasks do something like

`if ti.xcom_pull(key='state', task_ids=task_allowed_to_fail_id) == 'FAILED':
   raise ValueError('Force failure because upstream task has failed')`