# DAG marked as "success" if one task fails, because of trigger rule ALL_DONE

Tags: airflow

I have the following DAG with 3 tasks:

```
start --> special_task --> end
```

The task in the middle can succeed or fail, but `end` **must always** be executed (imagine this is a task for cleanly closing resources). For that, I used the [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) `ALL_DONE`:

```
end.trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
```

Using that, `end` is properly executed if `special_task` fails. However, since `end` is the last task and succeeds, the DAG is always marked as `SUCCESS`.

How can I configure my DAG so that if one of the tasks failed, the whole DAG is marked as `FAILED`?

### Example to reproduce

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils import trigger_rule

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    start_date=datetime.datetime.today(),
    schedule_interval=None
)

start = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command='echo start',
    dag=dag
)

special_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='special_task',
    bash_command='exit 1', # force failure
    dag=dag
)

end = BashOperator(
    task_id='end',
    bash_command='echo end',
    dag=dag
)
end.trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE

start.set_downstream(special_task)
special_task.set_downstream(end)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055582/how-to-mark-an-airflow-dag-run-as-failed-if-any-task-fails) seems to be related, but the answer does not suit my needs, since the downstream task `end` must be executed (hence the mandatory `trigger_rule`).

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to configure this at a DAG level. You could play with task flow to make something else propagate failure status, or use `on_failure_callback` to get notified about failed task.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas Actually, I already have an `on_failure_callback` to get notified, but I would like my DAG marked as `failed` in the Web UI.

Comment: If you create a dummy task and set it as downstream to `special_task` I'd expect failure to propagate. It is more of a bandage than a solution though.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas indeed, your solution works, thanks! But I thought an out-of-the-box solution exists since it's a pretty common use case. However, for people facing the same issue, I will answer the question with your solution and will mark it as an answer if no other solution is found. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@JustinasMarozas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091230/justinas-marozas) explained in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728441/airflow-dag-marked-as-success-if-one-task-fails-because-of-trigger-rule-all/51761821#comment90423248_51728441), a solution is to create a dummy task like :

```py
dummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='test',
    dag=dag
)
```

and bind it downstream to `special_task` :

```py
failing_task.set_downstream(dummy)
```

Thus, the DAG is marked as failed, and the `dummy` task is marked as `upstream_failed`.

Hope there is an out-of-the-box solution, but waiting for that, this solution does the job.

Answer (score 11):

I thought it was an interesting question and spent some time figuring out how to achieve it without an extra dummy task. It became a bit of a superfluous task, but here's the end result:

This is the full DAG:

```py
import airflow
from airflow import AirflowException
from airflow.models import DAG, TaskInstance, BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

default_args = {"owner": "airflow", "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(3)}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="finally_task_set_end_state",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
    description="Answer for question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728441",
)

start = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command="echo start", dag=dag)
failing_task = BashOperator(task_id="failing_task", bash_command="exit 1", dag=dag)


@provide_session
def _finally(task, execution_date, dag, session=None, **_):
    upstream_task_instances = (
        session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == dag.dag_id,
            TaskInstance.execution_date == execution_date,
            TaskInstance.task_id.in_(task.upstream_task_ids),
        )
        .all()
    )
    upstream_states = [ti.state for ti in upstream_task_instances]
    fail_this_task = State.FAILED in upstream_states

    print("Do logic here...")

    if fail_this_task:
        raise AirflowException("Failing task because one or more upstream tasks failed.")


finally_ = PythonOperator(
    task_id="finally",
    python_callable=_finally,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

succesful_task = DummyOperator(task_id="succesful_task", dag=dag)

start >> [failing_task, succesful_task] >> finally_
```

Look at the `_finally` function, which is called by the PythonOperator. There are a few key points here:

1. Annotate with `@provide_session` and add argument `session=None`, so you can query the Airflow DB with `session`.
2. Query all upstream task instances for the current task:

```py
upstream_task_instances = (
    session.query(TaskInstance)
    .filter(
        TaskInstance.dag_id == dag.dag_id,
        TaskInstance.execution_date == execution_date,
        TaskInstance.task_id.in_(task.upstream_task_ids),
    )
    .all()
)
```

3. From the returned task instances, get the states and check if `State.FAILED` is in there:

```py
upstream_states = [ti.state for ti in upstream_task_instances]
fail_this_task = State.FAILED in upstream_states
```

4. Perform your own logic:

```py
print("Do logic here...")
```

5. And finally, fail the task if `fail_this_task=True`:

```py
if fail_this_task:
    raise AirflowException("Failing task because one or more upstream tasks failed.")
```

The end result:

[image]

Comment: This works, but it incorrectly sets "finally" to failed, when it didn't. It would be better if you could mark it as upstream failed.

Comment: For current version (2.4.x) it is `State.UPSTREAM_FAILED` rather than `State.FAILED` to be looked for in `upstream_states`

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Bas Harenslak answer, a simpler _finally function which will check the state of all tasks (not only the upstream ones) can be:

```
def _finally(**kwargs):
    for task_instance in kwargs['dag_run'].get_task_instances():
        if task_instance.current_state() != State.SUCCESS and \
                task_instance.task_id != kwargs['task_instance'].task_id:
            raise Exception("Task {} failed. Failing this DAG run".format(task_instance.task_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in case you have a lot of tasks that can fail but trigger rule ALL_DONE of one task makes dag be in a success state at the end of your pipeline:

1. Collect your failing tasks into list:

`tasks = [failing_task, another_one]`

2. Make dummy finish operator with `trigger_rule="all_success"`

`finish = DummyOperator(task_id="finish", dag=dag, trigger_rule="all_success")`

3. Map each failing task on the operator

`mapped = list(map(lambda x: x >> finish, tasks))`

If one of the tasks fails, your dag marked as failed